# USB2244 card power is never supplied and USB port is not detected

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, microchip, usb-device, usb-host

I have been trying to use the USB2244 on a board but I can't seem to get it working and I am not sure what the problem is. I went over and over the datasheet but can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

I have attached my schematics. I have verified I have 3.3V, and also that the 1.8V rails are both being generated internally, I do have a 24MHz clock as well.

When I insert a MicroSD card I see the CD line go low but the CRD_PWR is never supplied. When the USB2244 is connected to system the USB port is not detected.

I can't figure out what I could be missing.

[image]

Comment: Show us your PCB layout too.

Comment: "MFD" is a poor choice for capacitor values, as it could be read as microfarad or millifarad (or, I guess, megafarad). Using uF is unambiguous.

Comment: @Finbarr - must be MegaFarads - 'M' is the SI standard prefix for 'Mega' after all ... ;)

Answer (score 5):

The largest problem is that the Type-C connector interface is not correctly implemented.

This is a common mistake when replacing a standard USB connector to a Type-C connector in a design.

It will power up with Type-A to Type-C cable just fine, but a Type-C host cannot determine that anything is even plugged in, so it will not give power out on VBUS.

The problem is that the CC pins are unconnected, while there should be a 5.1k resistor from each CC pin to GND.

However, if the VBUS does not give out power, there is no 3V3_SD supply, but card still is powered from MCU 3V3 supply - this makes little sense and having powered and unpowered components connected together via data lines is simply a hazard.

Comment: hi ,currently usb port only detected , can't sd card access. Card power pin not generating 3.3v and usb2244 ic over heating.I can't figure out what i could be missing ?